# How to read and print entire input of a string after a char shift?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I have a method that shifts rows in an given input string that circularly
shift the rows in each block in the following fashion. The first row remains the same. Shift the second row one position to the left. Shift the third row two positions to the left. Finally, shift the fourth row three positions to the left.

I get the correct shifting however it only prints the first 16 characters...any advice? output is supposed to be in 4x4 blocks. Already tried switching length of for loop to "inputStr.substring" over the entire string but got errors

This is what I have..

```
public static String shiftRows(String str, int shiftNum)
    {
        char[] out = new char[4];
        if(shiftNum==1)
        {
            out[0]=str.charAt(1);
            out[1]=str.charAt(2);
            out[2]=str.charAt(3);
            out[3]=str.charAt(0);
        }
        if(shiftNum==2)
        {
            out[0]=str.charAt(2);
            out[1]=str.charAt(3);
            out[2]=str.charAt(0);
            out[3]=str.charAt(1);
        }
        if(shiftNum==3)
        {
            out[0]=str.charAt(3);
            out[1]=str.charAt(0);
            out[2]=str.charAt(1);
            out[3]=str.charAt(2);
        }
        return new String(out);
    }
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    System.out.println("SHIFT ROWS: " );
        System.out.println();

    String[] input= new String[4];

    String[] output= new String[4];

    String inputStr = "WVOGJTXQHUHXICWYYMGHTRKQHQPWKYVGLPYSPWGOINTOFOPMO";

    for (int i = 0, n = 0; i < 4; i++, n+=4) {
        input[i] = inputStr.substring(0+n, 4+n);
    }

    output[0] = input[0];
    for(int i=1; i<4; i++)
    {
        output[i] = shiftRows(input[i],i);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(output[i]);
    }
```

My output:

```
SHIFT ROWS: 

WVOG
TXQJ
HXHU
YICW
```

Output I want:

```
WVOG
TXQJ
HXHU
YICW

YMGH
RKQT
PWHQ
GKYV

LPYS
WGOP
TOIN
MFOP

OAAA
AAAA
AAAA
AAAA
```

Comment: Why do you create to Scanners on System.in? They dont get used.

Comment: meant to take those out, originally I had asked for user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretend shiftRows(s, 0) just returns s (which I'd do for real). Then you're setting output[i] to shiftRows(input[i], i) for i 0..3. shiftRows always returns a 4 character string, so all elements of output will be a 4 character string, you're printing all the elements of output once, so you're getting 4, 4 character strings, as expected.

Also, when you're chopping up inputStr, think about n. It's incremented by 4 4 times (once for each time i is incremented by 1, and that happens 4 times), so it only goes from 0 to 16, so you're also only consuming the first 16 characters of inputStr.

I think you want to break the for loop into an inner and outer loop. The outer will consume (figuratively, there's no reason to actually extract the characters) chunks of 16 characters from inputStr, and the inner loop will break those 16 into the 4 groups of 4, shift them, and print them.